# Why does the Navbar only toggle to show and not hide on links?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been developing a site, the site has a mobile nav bar which expands from the side. The Javascript and HTML show the current state where I have tried to slide the nav bar back in once a link has been pressed. (By slide I mean toggle the nav)

```js
const mobileNavShow = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav-show');
  const mobileNavHide = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav-hide');

  document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-nav-toggle').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      mobileNavToogle();
    })
  });

  function mobileNavToogle() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('mobile-nav-active');
    mobileNavShow.classList.toggle('d-none');
    mobileNavHide.classList.toggle('d-none');
  }
```

```html
 <i class="mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav-show bi bi-list"></i>
      <i class="mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav-hide d-none bi bi-x"></i>
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#hero" class="active hoverable">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#why-us" class="hoverable">Why Choose Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services-list" class="hoverable">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services-cards" class="hoverable">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team" class="hoverable">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" class="hoverable">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Mobile Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 1279px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 9997;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    padding: 50px 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(27, 47, 69, 0.9);
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 9998;
  }

  .navbar a,
  .navbar a:focus {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: var(--font-default);
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .navbar a i,
  .navbar a:focus i {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  .navbar a:hover,
  .navbar .active,
  .navbar .active:focus,
  .navbar li:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navbar .dropdown ul,
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(20, 35, 51, 0.6);
  }

  .navbar .dropdown>.dropdown-active,
  .navbar .dropdown .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
    display: block;
  }

  .mobile-nav-show {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-size: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .mobile-nav-hide {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  .mobile-nav-active {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .mobile-nav-active .navbar {
    right: 0;
  }

  .mobile-nav-active .navbar:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    background: rgba(27, 47, 69, 0.7);
    z-index: 9996;
  }
}
```

I need someone to review this and tell me where I'm going wrong or provide some insight into where I can go from here.

TIA.

Comment: You got CSS too?

Comment: I have added the CSS @SuperJumbo

Comment: Hrm, somethings not right. The navbar should have a max width of 400px no? When I run the snippet it's almost getting to 500px